# nginx Configuration to Modify Response Header Links

Tags: nginx

We are using nginx for load balancing and handling SSL of an API. Requests are forwarded to Tomcat instances. Since Tomcat does not use SSL, all hyperlinks that are provided by Tomcat use `http` rather than `https`.

We use module `ngx_http_sub_module` to modify all hyperlinks in the response **body** and replace `http` by `https`. This is working already.

However, all hyperlinks in the response **header**, for example in the `Location` or `Link` headers are **not** replaced.

Is there any other module that can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

See the [proxy_redirect directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect).  For more complicated proxying, getting this setting correct gets difficult, but for simpler cases their provided examples should prove illuminating.

I still haven't found a way to handle Link: headers reliably.

Comment: Thanks. According to the documentation, this is only for changing the response header fields `Location` and `Refresh`. I need to change the header field `Link`.

Comment: That's correct.  By my read, there have been some changes recently in the nginx codebase for recognizing link headers, but nothing yet to manage them.  If this is, as in my case, for dealing with wordpress, we worked around it programmatically (suppressed them in header, and added them as tags in the html).